# Do nonsense and bull**** have corresponding plural forms?

Tags: grammatical-number, offensive-language, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

For example, I've heard *nonsenses*, but I've never heard *bullshits*.

Why one is plural and the other is singular? They mean the same thing.

Comment: Bullshits is nonsense

Comment: _[Nonsense](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonsense)_ is a singular non-count noun. It isn't used in plural form. If you heard it, it was a mistake. If there's a contrived context in which it can be used in plural form, it's strictly an outlier & can be summarily dismissed as an inconsequential freak.

Comment: @Bill what about this?? http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonsenses#English

Comment: @BillFranke Um, are there any **non**-singular "non-count" nouns?

Comment: @Raghav: Bullshit! I'll stand with the [Macmillan Dictionary online](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/nonsense). I said right here in this forum a month or two or three ago that I didn't trust Wiktionary. My grandmother used to repeat that old cliche "Believe nothing you hear and only half of what you read". I will add to that another cliche: Don't believe everything you see on the Internet.

Comment: @tchrist: Yeah, [_water_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/water). Look it up.

Comment: It is possible to have bullshits: http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7131/7497276212_950bf6ee4b_z.jpg

Comment: @BillFranke: I would like to agree with you, but unfortunately I saw your post on the Internet :)

Comment: @tchrist: 'troops' - a single infantryman is never referred to as 'a troop'.

Comment: @Shyam: An interesting photo, but a single piece of bull dung would be called a _turd_ or, by analogy, a _bull chip_ or a _bull apple_, not a _bullshit_.

Comment: @TimL: Good point, but I did say "Don't believe **everything**", not "Don't believe **anything**". Words are a constant source of trouble, aren't they?

Comment: Wow wow. So there is no such thing as nonsenses? Only nonsense. Anyway why the downvotes :(

Comment: @Mitch; *A troop* certainly does exist, and was probably the origin of *troops* as a count noun (though indeed it never meant *a soldier*).

Comment: @Mitch A group of soldiers is a troop of soldiers.  (As is a group of monkeys.)  A single soldier is not a troop.  See [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/can-a-single-person-be-a-troop?src=defrecirc-indulgeyourinner)

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of a plural of *bullshit*

> It is so because bullshit is considered to be uncountable.
>   [[reference link]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bullshit)

But also consider this that there exists a word *bullshits*:

> Bullshits >> Third-person singular simple present indicative form of bullshit.
>   [[reference link]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bullshits#English)

As far as *nonsense* is considered, it is usually uncountable [[reference link]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonsense)
and the plural for it is nonsenses[[reference link]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonsenses#English).

Read this [article](http://rwc.hunter.cuny.edu/reading-writing/on-line/countable.html) in order to have a grasp of nouns which can be either countable or uncountable.

Comment: And what about nonsense? Are senses countable?

Comment: @JimThio: _Senses_ are one thing, but _nonsense_ is quite another.

Comment: So there is no such thing as nonsenses either. Only nonsense?

Comment: yes, nonsenses exists only in few places and that too not widely supported. Above also the wikitonary links only says it is usually uncountable.

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.